# Dynamically generate a 2d array from JSON with varying columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a json where I need to organize in the form of 2d array and the number columns are known to be found after the json iteration and they are to be numbered #1 #2 for multiple sets of their occurances for the corresponding item as shown in the below image/sheet

The expected output is 2d array

```
[
    ["firstName", "middleName", "lastName", "addresses: #1 type", "addresses: #1 poBox", "addresses: #1 streetAddress", "addresses: #1 city", "addresses: #1 region", "addresses: #1 postalCode", "addresses: #1 country", "addresses: #2 type", "addresses: #2 poBox", "addresses: #2 streetAddress", "addresses: #2 city", "addresses: #2 region", "addresses: #2 postalCode", "addresses: #3 poBox", "addresses: #3 region", "addresses: #3 postalCode", "addresses: #2 country", "photos: #1 url", "photos: #1 default", "photos: #2 url", "photos: #2 default"],
    ["John", "Joseph", "Briggs", "home", 111, "", "City1", "", "1ER001", "USA", "work", 222, "", "City2", "Region2", "1ER002", "", "", "", "", "photo.org/person1", "TRUE", "photo.org/person1", "TRUE"],
    ["Bill", "", "Thatcher", "home", "", "", "City3", "Region3", "1ER003", "USA", "work", 444, "", "", "Region4", "1ER004", 555, "Region5", "1ER005", "", "", "", "", ""]
]
```

[The expected output is also shown here for better clarity](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16PgTkBrcK174MpynkrPExAEPKtuJpLnRyfmnoxstlJM/edit#gid=0)

Please note that the red headers columns contain no data and there is no need to be in 2d array output. There are 1000 crowds (rows) with similar data like some dont have postal code and some missing middlename and some with missing photos

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<script>



var crowds = [{
        "name": [{
            "firstName": "John",
            "middleName": "Joseph",
            "lastName": "Briggs"
        }],
        "addresses": [{
                "type": "home",
                "poBox": "111",
                "city": "City1",
                "postalCode": "1ER001",
                "country": "USA"
            },
            {
                "type": "work",
                "poBox": "222",
                "city": "City2",
                "region": "Region2",
                "postalCode": "1ER002"
            }
        ],
        "photos": [{
                "url": "photo.org/person1",
                "default": true
            },
            {
                "url": "imagur.org/person1",
                "default": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": [{
            "firstName": "Bill",
            "lastName": "Thatcher"
        }],
        "addresses": [{
                "type": "home",
                "city": "City3",
                "region": "Region3",
                "postalCode": "1ER003",
                "country": "USA"
            },
            {
                "type": "work",
                "poBox": "444",
                "region": "Region4",
                "postalCode": "1ER004"
            }
            {
                "poBox": "555",
                "region": "Region5",
                "postalCode": "1ER005"
            }            
        ]
    }
]



var rows = [];
var headerRow = [];


crowds.forEach(function(crowd) {
    var cols = [];
    for (key in crowd) {
        headerRow.push(key + ":#")
        cols.push(crowd[key].firstName)
                cols.push(crowd[key].middleName)
                        cols.push(crowd[key].lastName)
    }
    rows.push(cols)
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(headerRow.concat(rows)))

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

```
function flatten(obj, res = {}, key = '') {
    let add = (d, s) => key ? key + d + s : s;

    if (Array.isArray(obj))
        obj.forEach((v, n) => flatten(v, res, add(' #', n + 1)))
    else if (typeof obj === 'object')
        Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => flatten(v, res, add(': ', k)))
    else
        res[key] = obj
    return res
}
```

applied to your data

```
let flats = crowds.map(obj => flatten(obj))
console.log(flats)
```

this would return a list of "flattened" objects like this:

```
[
  {
    'name #1: firstName': 'John',
    'name #1: middleName': 'Joseph',
    'name #1: lastName': 'Briggs',
    'addresses #1: type': 'home',
    ...etc
  },
  {
    'name #1: firstName': 'Bill',
    'name #1: lastName': 'Thatcher',
    'addresses #1: type': 'home',
    ...etc
  }
]
```

Now you'll have to build a union of all keys in all flattened objects:

```
function combineKeys(objs) {
    let keys = objs.reduce((k, obj) => k.concat(Object.keys(obj)), [])
    return [...new Set(keys)]
}

let keys = combineKeys(flats)
```

and finally make a table from the list of keys:

```
let table = flats.map(f => keys.map(k => f[k] ?? ''))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @georg could you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68847172/flattening-json-with-an-key-exclusion-list